# Swift Xcode, How to navigate to view controller once logged In

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, navigation

I am unsure of how to proceed, once I have logged in on my app to navigate to a new view controller.

[image]

Many Thanks
Shaan

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a containerVC which shows further content or a loginViewController and controls whether the user is still logged in or not?

Comment: First never post screen shots of your code, paste the code that is giving you issues.  Second you need to read up on creating segues.  Also you need to add more explanation as how you expect the app to perform.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask